# Event rule not triggering lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

```
SNSLambdaScheduleRule:
Type: AWS::Events::Rule
Properties:
  RoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::119497028878:role/LabRole"
  Description: "Schedule rule for SNS Lambda"
  ScheduleExpression: "rate(2 minutes)"
  State: ENABLED
  Targets:
    - Arn: !GetAtt SNSSubscriptionLambda.Arn
      Id: "TargetFunctionV1"
```

I am trying to achieve a functionality where a lambda is called every 2 minutes. It does get deployed to aws under Amazon event bridge>buses>rules however it does not trigger lambda every 2 mins.

Last time i tried to create similar functionality via UI i used Amazon event bridge>Scheduler>schedule which trigger lambdas every 2 mins. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Used following code to schedule Lambda via EventBridge (Events)

```
  ScheduledRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      ScheduleExpression: "rate(10 minutes)"
      Description: "Scheduled invocation of LambdaFunction"
      State: "ENABLED"  # Enable the rule
      Targets:
        - Arn: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn  # ARN of your Lambda function
          Id: "Lambda-ScheduedRun"
          Input:
            !Sub |
                {
                  "Test":"InputToLambdas"
                }
  AllowInvokeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: events.amazonaws.com
      SourceAccount: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
      SourceArn: !GetAtt ScheduledRule.Arn
```